# Simulate multiple GPUs on a machine

Tags: gpgpu, torch, multi-gpu

I'm trying to write torch code meant to run on multiple GPUs.

I would like to ensure the program does not exceed the memory available on these GPU, I would like to collect information about whether the GPUs are waiting for data from another computation, collect statistics on how often data is copied from memory to the GPU's memory, etc.

For all of these purposes, it seems like it would be helpful to simulate the presence of multiple GPUs on the system. Of course you could also **have** multiple GPUs on the system, but that seems wasteful if I'm mostly using it to debug.

Is it possible to do that, either with torch directly, or at the OS level on Linux?

Comment: How about pytorch
https://www.run.ai/guides/multi-gpu/pytorch-multi-gpu-4-techniques-explained
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html

Comment: This explains how to use multiple GPU, not how to simulate multiple GPUs on a system to check if your multi-GPU code is working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if emulating multiple GPUs using just one (or none) is not straight-forward. Apparently it is possible to achieve "something close" through the [CUDA driver API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875188/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-multiple-gpus-with-one).
But I can't claim that I would know how to apply this.

To collect the the data you need [`torch.profiler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/profiler.html) seems to be the way to go.